# I need to display the result of i var n = d.getTimezoneOffset(); in javascript in a PHP echo command

Tags: javascript, php

I am not familiar with Ajax, and am very poor with java script, but need
the results of a javascript function var n=f.getTimezoneOffset(); in javascript intp a simple PHP echo command.
How do I do this?

I need to display the timezone offset at the bottom of web page http://gemini-2.com  A user can input there address, and get back the proper Latitude and longitude to input into there telescope controller. They also need to input the time zone offset from UTC.  I am trying to give them that answer.  It needs to be from where there computer is located, not from my server which is in UT.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're asking. JavaScript executes in the browser; PHP on the server. Everything you see in your browser has already been produced by PHP and PHP is no longer in the picture. Can you explain clearly what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Why would you need it in a PHP `echo()` command? `echo()` simply outputs a variable back to the DOM... and JavaScript already has access to the DOM. Are you asking how to store a JavaScript variable as a PHP variable?

Comment: I don't know enough about how to do this to answer that question. I have a form at the bottom of http:\\gemini-2.com where a user can input there address.  It gives the the Latitude and longitude in the proper format to enter into there Telescope controller handset.  the handset also requires the timezone offset from UTD.  That is what I am trying to put out with an echo command just like I do the Latitude and Longitude.  Hope this helps explain what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't process JavaScript from PHP. You need use a PHP function that like this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-offset-get.php

Comment: The other thing I was looking at was using the timezonedb, command, https://api.timezonedb.com/v2/get-time-zone?key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=json&by=position&lat=YOUR_LATITUDE&lng=YOUR_LONGITUDE  But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to put the latitude and longitude  into the link string.  I also have not been able to get the results returned into the proper format to extract just the time zone offset.  This is really a complex problem for a newbe.

Answer (score 0):

This code was provided to me from a follow astronomer, and it works great.

```
    <?php
    $APIKEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $SVCURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/';
    function lookupTimezone($lat, $long) 
    {
        $time = intval(microtime(TRUE));
        $service_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/' . 
     'json? 
        location=' . $lat . ',' . $long . '&key=' . $APIKEY . '&timestamp=' . 
        $time;

        $curl = curl_init($service_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
        if ($curl_response === false) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . 
        var_export($info));
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        $decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
        if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status 
         == 'ERROR') {
            die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
        }
       $dst = $decoded->{'dstOffset'};
       $offset = ($decoded->{'rawOffset'} + $dst)/3600;
       return $offset;
   }

   $result =lookupTimezone(40.753249, -74.001442); 
   echo 'GMT Offset is: ' . $result;
   ?>
```